# Avoiding small gaps between sprites due to linear Filtering in libGDX

Tags: java, graphics, opengl-es, libgdx

I am trying to render a laser beam for my libGDX project. I used multiple single sprites that are positioned side by side, depending on the filter these are the varying results:

- Left side shows the rendering result using Nearest Filter
- Right side shows the rendering result using Linear Filter

[image: Laser Example]

The picture shows on the right side small gaps between the shift of one sprite to the next.

The picture on the left using Nearest Filtering does not have these gaps but has a pixelated look I'm trying to avoid.

Is there a way to get a smooth looking laser beam like the one using linear filtering but without the small gaps?

Comment: Pad your sprites with a couple perimeters worth of duplicate edge pixels. TexturePacker can do this automatically.

Comment: I am using already TexturePacker with edge padding activated. I tried different sizes of  duplicated edge pixels (up to 10, just to be sure), but the results still show the gaps.

Comment: You can change blend mode. So only one of the lazer can shown at those joint points.

Comment: If possible I want to stick to additive blending since it gives a very nice effect especially if one laser overlays another.